# Meteor simple schema for mongo geo location data

Tags: mongodb, meteor, schema

I want to create an admin form for my meteor app; I was going to try Ogno Admin before resorting to building one from scratch but I'm not sure if it can support the data in the format that I need. My current app data goes into mongo like this:

```js
Beaches.insert({
    "name": "Entry name",
    /* location stored like this so I can use mongo $near queries */
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-5.0990296,50.110757]
    },
    /* could be many images, minimum 1 */
    "images": [
        {
            "url": "image1.jpg",
            "caption": "Image caption"
        }
    ],
    "shortDesc": "A delightful description...",
    /* fixed list of attributes stored as objects */
    "attributes": {
        "attr 1": {
            "score": 2,
            "text": "attr1 text"
        },
```

Could I write a simple schema to support the different arrays/objects above (esp. location coords)? They have to be square bracket formatted [lng, lat] - and would ogno admin work with this, or would I have to write the custom admin stuff? It might be easier for me to build the admin site in something else and get that to output JSON data for Meteor.

## Update with possible schema code

```js
Beaches = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  location: {
    type: [Object]
  },
    location.$.type: {
    /* how do I force '"type" : "Point" into every entry?
       use 'autovalue' with the .clean() function?*/
    },
      location.$.coordinates: {
      /* how do I ensure a [x,y] array in here? */
    },
  images: {
    type: [Object]
  },
    "images.$.url": {
        type: String
    },
    "images.$.caption": {
        type: String
    },
  attributes: {
    type: [Object]
  },
  /* note that my attributes above are all prefixed with a 'name'
     eg. "attr 1" : {}
     I'm not sure how to declare these either!
  */
  ...
});
```

Comment: Yes simple-schema works with location coords. Do you have any efforts? I dont know Ogno admin but in the docs is written that they validate with simple-schema so it should work with a simple-schema.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to format the location - especially the coordinates array - I don't want to prefix the data with 'lng' and 'lat', and Simple Schema doesn;t have an 'Array' type (only String, Number, Boolean and Object)

Comment: Simple Schema does have an array type. `[object]` Go here (https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema/) and search for "To indicate the presence of an array"

Answer (score 10):

Hmm I dont know exactly the solution to your process of saving geocoords. But if you want to save lng and lat you have to pass a prefix. Why? Well geocoords have different validation ranges. Latitude is only available from -90 to 90 and Longitude from -180 to 180. If you dont save a prefix how do you want to ensure which is which coordinate? Another hint I have done false someday is to store the coords in longitude, latitude order.

The schema I am using looks like this:

```
GeocoordsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  lng: {
    type : Number,
    decimal: true,
    min: -180,
    max: 180
  }, 
  lat: {
    type : Number,
    decimal: true,
    min: -90,
    max: 90
  }
});
```

Now you create nested schemas. Just extend GeocoordsSchema with LocationSchema  and add a attribute.

```
LocationSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  type : {
    type : String,
    autoValue: function() {
      return "Point";
    }
  },
  coordinate: {
    type: GeocoordsSchema 
  }
});
```

If you want to have an array of LocationSchema than you can wrap the schema in [] brackets.

```
BeachesSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  loc: {
    type: [LocationSchema]
  }
});
```

I havent tested but thats the way how I create and nest different schemas. Well this solution needs an identifier of lat and lng. Why dont you want to prefix your data?

Comment: This is great, thanks so much chaosborne. I didn't think I wanted to prefix my latlng coords because my current working schema is (possibly wrongly) based on a $near search outlined in the mongo docs - but your code looks really good so I'm going to try changing my data this morning to see if I can get it working this way!

Comment: This looks like a great answer - will give it a shot.

Comment: Tested and seems it's not working with 2ds index. Simply GeocoordsSchema is an object but not an array of numbers.

Answer (score 6):

My solution is like the one of chaosbohne, but I define the whole location via a single sub-schema and some custom validations like this:

```
SimpleSchema.messages
  lonOutOfRange: '[label] longitude should be between -90 and 90'
  latOutOfRange: '[label] latitude should be between -180 and 180'

LocationSchema = new SimpleSchema
  type:
    type: String,
    allowedValues: ['Point']
  coordinates:
    type: [Number]
    decimal: true
    minCount: 2
    maxCount: 2
    custom: ->
      return "lonOutOfRange" unless -90 <= @value[0] <= 90
      return "latOutOfRange" unless -180 < @value[1] <= 180
```

Where possible, I use the existing validation features of SimpleSchema. The coordinates are limited via `minCount` and `maxCount`, though I could have used another line in the custom validation function aswell. Something like this:

```
SimpleSchema.messages
  needsLatLong: '[label] should be of form [longitude, latitude]'
  lonOutOfRange: '[label] longitude should be between -90 and 90'
  latOutOfRange: '[label] latitude should be between -180 and 180'

LocationSchema = new SimpleSchema
  type:
    type: String,
    allowedValues: ['Point']
  coordinates:
    type: [Number]
    decimal: true
    custom: ->
      return "needsLatLong" unless @value.length is 2
      return "lonOutOfRange" unless -90 <= @value[0] <= 90
      return "latOutOfRange" unless -180 < @value[1] <= 180
```

Now in your example you would write:

```
Beaches = new SimpleSchema
  name:
    type: String
  location:
    type: LocationSchema
    index: '2dsphere'
  images:
    type: [Object]
  "images.$.url":
    type: String
  "images.$.caption":
    type: String
  attributes:
    type: [Object]
```

Note the `index: '2dsphere'` so that MongoDB knows about the index type.

Comment: Terrific, thanks for sharing that! Should the indices of lat and lon be switched, since Mongo says "Always store coordinates in longitude, latitude order."?

Comment: Thanks! You are right, that was a typo in the validation message. Fixed. :)

Comment: Also need to switch to put lon first in the custom: validations, so that lonOutOfRange checks @value[0], right?

Answer (score 2):

The OP might have solved this by now, Still I would like to post my answer to give back some love to the StackOverflow community.

First of all, create a `PlaceSchema` as follows:

```
LocationSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    "type":{
        type: String,
        allowedValues: ["Point"]
    },
    "coordinates":{
        type: Array,
        minCount: 2,
        maxCount: 2
    },
    "coordinates.$":{
        type: Number,
        decimal: true,
        custom: function(){
            if(!(-90 <= this.value[0] <= 90))
                return "lonOutOfRange" ;
            if(!(-180 <= this.value[1] <= 180))
                return "latOutOfRange" ;
        }

    },
    "name": {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
});



LocationSchema.messages = {
  lonOutOfRange: 'Longitude out of range', // Must be between -90 and 90
  latOutOfRange: 'Latitude out of range' // Must be between -180 and 180
}
```

Now use it inside your main schema:

```
BeachSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    location: {
        type: LocationSchema // HERE
    }
    // ...
});
```

Then attach the schema to your collection:

```
Beaches.attachSchema(BeachSchema);//*/
```

You might also consider adding a `2dsphere` index by:

```
Beaches._ensureIndex({ "location": "2dsphere"});
```